# Link activo al hacer clic sobre él

Tags: javascript, css3

He estado buscando en stackoverflow en inglés y solo encuentro respuestas utilizando jQuery.

Necesito que al hacer clic sobre un enlace ese mismo se mantenga activo con un determinado color, posteriormente al cerrarlo que vuelva a recuperar sus propiedades principales y pseudoclases, es decir cuando pase el ratón por encima me muestre otro color.

Al hacer clic sobre la función:

```
targetSolutions.addEventListener('click', () => {
let target = document.querySelector('.sub-menu-1');
target.style.display = (target.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
```

Agrego dentro de la función para conseguir el resultado:

```
 var link = document.getElementById('linkSoluciones');
 if (target.style.display === 'block') {
    link.style.color = (target.style.color = '#fffffff') ? '#ff5722' : '#ffffff';
```

Hago uso de un operador ternario donde si el target es de color blanco, al hacer clic sobre el cambiar al color naranja, sino:

```
link.style.color = '#ffffff';
```

Lo hace todo, pero cuando vuelvo a pasar el ratón por encima del enlace la pseudoclase :hover no hace nada, supongo que es por que le digo que si no se cumple el condicional me devuelva color:'#ffffff'.

¿Cual es la solución?

Solo Javascript o CSS.

Comment: Cuando dices: >> "posteriormente al cerrarlo que vuelva a recuperar sus propiedades".
Te refieres a que este enlace abrirá alguna ventana modal? o a que te refieres?. Puedes explicarte un poco mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Abre una ventana modal, no puse todo el código, cuando haces clic  sobre el enlace pasa de blanco a naranja y hasta que no cierre la ventana no retoma su antiguo color, lo hace todo menos  cuando pasabas el cursor mostraba el color naranja con la pseudo :hover. Un ejemplo claro es en el menú de esta misma página, donde pone StackExchange, eso es lo que busco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues bien, espero haber entendido lo que estas buscando, este `script` contiene un modal, porque no se cual usas, tendrías que reemplazarlo a tus necesidades, pero cuidando el uso de algunas clases.

```js
//Buscamos todos los elementos tipo anchor que NO contengan la clase; cerrar
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a:not(.cerrar)");
if(a && a.length > 0){ //Validación 
  /*
  Una vez que tenemos todo nuestro Array del querySelector, procedemos a iterarlo.
  Le asignamos el evento onclick a cada elemento iterado.
  Dentro del evento verificamos la existencia de la clase; seleccion, en dado caso de NO encontrarla, entonces le agregamos esa clase mediante la propiedad className. Ahora como método alternativo (y por si algo ocurriera) si ya tiene la clase selección, entonces la reemplazamos por nada,vacio, etc. Y al final ejecutamos la funcion llamada z.
  */ 
  a.forEach((aa)=>{ aa.onclick = ()=> ( aa.className =  aa.className.search(/seleccion/g) <0 ? aa.className+" seleccion" : aa.className.replace(/seleccion/g,"") )&&z() });
}
//Esta funcion z
function z(){
  // Buscamos el elemento a con la clase .cerrar
  var x = document.querySelector("a.cerrar");
  if(x){ //Validación
    //Ahora buscamos todos los elementos que tengan la clase; seleccion. 
    var b = document.querySelectorAll(".seleccion");
    /*Le agregamos el evento click e iteramos los array, al final vamos a reemplazar la clase seleccion por un vacio.*/
    x.onclick = () => (
      b.forEach((aa) =>{
        aa.className = aa.className.replace(/seleccion/g,"")
      })
    );
  }

  
}
```

```css
.enlace > a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
  background: yellow;
}
a {
  color: purple;
}
a:hover:not(.seleccion){
  color: blue;
}
.seleccion{
  color: orange;
  background: yellow;
}
.seleccion:hover{
  color: white;
  background: orange!important;
}
div > a.cerrar{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.modal-contenido{
  background-color:aqua;
  width:300px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 20% auto;
  position: relative;
}
.modal{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#miModal:target{
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#miModal">Abre Modal</a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#miModal">Liga 2</a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#miModal">Liga 3</a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#miModal">Liga 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="miModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-contenido">
    <a class="cerrar" href="#">X</a>
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Contenido</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Si, eso era, el modal lo tengo hecho, acabo de personalizarlo y funciona correctamente. Gracias, saludos.